# Is there a Visual Studio Express template project for a 3-tier web application with WCF service and database?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am new to .Net development, and I want to create a 3-tier C# web application (probably MVC on front end) with WCF web service for updating a database.  Is there a Visual Studio Express 2012 template project for this type of application?  It seems like such a common architecture that I'm surprised that I can't find a template or sample, although I have found several samples that do parts of it.  Since I'm new and don't know exactly what to search for, I just want to make sure that I haven't overlooked something that would expedite my efforts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your solution to have two project to make this work. There isn't a default project that is automatically hooked up for this scenario. First you would want to select a new project >> ASP.NET MVC X Application. Once the project is created you can right click on the solution and and a new project. Add a new WCF service application. This way you have two projects in your solution. One for the front end and one for the middle tier. You can use the entity framework alongside your middle tier project to create an easy to use data model.

Comment: Thanks.  Once I do that, how do I get the MVC app to access the WCF service?  Do I also need a host app for the WCF service?

Comment: You need to host the service (IIS, self-hosting or Windows Service), and then you add a reference to the service in your MVC app.